# HaProxy rstring (regex) issue on response (http-check)

Tags: regex, haproxy

I am trying to using rstring option for http-check to validate, if service is 100% operational.

What I am trying to do:

```
http-check expect rstring ^{"status":"UP","components"
```

Response from endpoint:

```
{"status":"UP","components":{"db":{"status":"UP","details":{"database":"Microsoft SQL Server","validationQuery":"isValid()"}},"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":57470816256,"free":16902025216,"threshold":10485760,"exists":true}},"hikariConnectionPool":{"status":"UP","details":{"activeConnections":0,"maxPoolSize":40}},"indexStatus":{"status":"GREEN"},"ping":{"status":"UP"}}
```

regex `^{"status":"UP","components"` should be ok, but I guess I am missing somethig.

Comment: You may need to escape the `{` character, e.g. `^\{"status":"UP","components"`

Comment: {"status":{"code":"UP","description":""},... I tried like: http-check expect rstring ^\{"status":\{"code":"UP","description":""\} but it is not working

Comment: What exactly is coming from the endpoint? Your question and your comment contradict each other on that. Also, note that any whitespace in the endpoint response would also need to be taken care of.

Comment: this: `{"status":{"code":"DEGRADED","description":""},"details":{"dbConnectionPool":{"status":{"code":"DEGRADED","description":""},"...`

this is how I am doing: `http-check expect rstring ((^{\"status\":{\"code\":\"UP\")|(^{\"status\":{\"code\":\"DEGRADED\"))` but it only works for "UP". If in reponse code is "DEGRADED" it will remove endpoint from LB, which is not ok.

Comment: Maybe this works for you? `http-check expect rstring ^{\"status\":{\"code\":\"(UP|DEGRADED)\"`